# What is the correct definition of the Cesàro summation of autocovariances?

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, stochastic-processes, convergence, ergodic

I'm a little confused regarding a mathematical definition (Cesàro summation) and its application to stationary time series. First, consider the definition given by Wikipedia, adapting to autovariances. According to this definition, the [Cesàro sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation) of the autocovariances would be given by: let $(\gamma_\ell)_{\ell=1}^{\infty}$ be the sequence of autocovariances, and let:
$$s_k = \sum_{\ell=1}^{k} \gamma_\ell$$
be its k-th partial sum.  The value of the limit
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n s_k = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{\ell=1}^{k} \gamma_\ell = A, \quad A \in \mathbb R $$
is called the Cesàro sum of the series $\sum_{\ell=1}^{\infty} \gamma_\ell$ and we say that the sequence $(\gamma_\ell)_{\ell=1}^{\infty}$ is Cesàro summable.

On the other hand, Hansen in his book Econometrics (see Ergodicity section) states the following:
[image]

Furthermore, see how in this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/407004/misunderstanding-of-time-series-autocovariance), the author of the answer also seems to use the same definition as Hansen.

Well, for me the two definitions are not the same and this is a little confusing for those looking for mathematically well-established definitions. Perhaps due to my lack of experience, I may be missing something obvious. Could anyone help me better understand this impasse?

Comment: Could you point to the difference(s) you perceive between the two statements?

Comment: Hum, the Hansen definition states that $\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{s_k}{k}= 0$. On the other hand, the convergence of $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n s_k$, as $n \to \infty$, implies that $\sum_{k=1}^n s_k \leq n ^r$, with $0<r<1$ (here, $\leq$ means that the asymptotic growth is, at most, the same as $n^r$, as $n \to \infty$). Perhaps now it is possible to show that this implies Hanse's definition, but even so, Cesàro summation's definitions are definitely not the same.